# Are two standard normal random variables always independent?

Tags: normal-distribution, independence

I learned that the standard normal distribution is unique because the mean and variance are fixed at 0 and 1 respectively. By this fact, I wonder if any two standard random variables must be independent.

Comment: Why should they be..? Independence has nothing to do with distribution.

Comment: Consider $X$ and $X$. They are not independent.

Comment: You may find this helpful from a practical standpoint.
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15011/generate-a-random-variable-with-a-defined-correlation-to-an-existing-variable

Comment: In addition to the nice examples given consider generally a bivariate normal distribution with N(0,!) marginal distributions.  It is possible to have any correlation between -1 and 1.  The examples below are all special cases.  As an aside it is possible for two standard normal variables to be dependent but not have a bivariate distribution.

Comment: I notice Batman gives a general result that may be the same as what I am suggesting.  The Y = -X case has correlation -1 and so is a degenerate form of a bivariate normal.  I haven't seen an example here(on this post) that illustrate a case that isn't bivariate normal.

Comment: @MichaelChernick - Good point. I added an answer for that.

Answer (score 42):

The answer is no. For example, if $X$ is a standard random variable, then $Y=-X$ follows the same statistics, but $X$ and $Y$ are clearly dependent.

Answer (score 26):

No, there is no reason to believe that any two standard gaussians are independent.

Here's a simple mathematical construction.  Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ *are* two independent standard normal variables.  Then the pair

$$ X, \frac{X + Y}{\sqrt{2}}$$

are two *dependent* standard normal variables.  So, as long as their are two *independent* normal variables, there must be two *dependent* ones.

The second variable is normal because any linear combination of independent normal variables is again normal.  The $\sqrt{2}$ is there to make the variance equal to $1$.

$$ V \left(\frac{X + Y}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^2} (V(X) + V(Y)) = 1 $$

Intuitively, these are dependent because knowing the value of $X$ gives you additional information you can use to predict the value of the second variable.  For example, if you know that $X = x$, then the conditional expectation of the second variable is

$$ E \left[\frac{X + Y}{\sqrt{2}} \mid X = x \right] = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} $$

Answer (score 7):

Here's a fairly wide answer:

Let $X,Y$ be jointly Gaussian random variables (i.e. for any $a,b$ real numbers, $a X + bY$ has a Gaussian distribution). Then, $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])]=0$ (i.e. they are uncorrelated). See [these notes](http://hajek.ece.illinois.edu/ECE534Notes.html), for example, for details.

How can you generate standard normal random variables which are not independent? Pick your favorite matrix of the form $\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & p \\ p & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ such that $(\lambda-1)^2 - p^2$ has positive roots in $\lambda$. Then, apply the Cholesky decompositon to $\Sigma= R R^T$. Then, take two independent standard normal random variables $U,V$ and then the vector $R \begin{bmatrix} U \\ V \end{bmatrix}$ has standard normal components, but the components are independent if and only if $p=0$.

Answer (score 5):

A non-bivariate normal example (as  Michael Chernick  suggests in the comments):

Let $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\pi} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} & xy\geq 0 \\
0 & o.w. 
\end{cases}$.

This is not a bivariate normal distribution, but a simple integral shows that both marginals are standard normal. They're obviously not independent since $f_{X,Y}(x,y) \neq f_X(x) f_Y(y)$.