I need to reverse engineer a dataset. How can I do?
For an econometrics assignment, my teacher has given me the result of the regression of a scientific article (see table and regression) and the exercise consists in inverting the data set that led to this regression. Then we have to run a regression and find exactly the same results.
Results of the regression
The regression
Note that the model is a linear probability model and the regression coefficients may be interpreted as the incremental changes in the subscription likelihood.
I managed to find results really close from the one of the paper for the non-extended model about  property (see the first column of the table), but I don't manage to find correct results for the extended model about property (second column). Can you tell me what is wrong ?
## generate a simulated data set
set.seed(8)
# number of observations
N <- 600

# Generation of the random binary variables x1 and x2
x1 <- as.numeric(rnorm(N) > 0)
x2 <- as.numeric(rnorm(N) > 0)

# Interaction 
x3 <- x1 * x2

# NOTE FOR LATER : TO DEFINE AS LOGARITHMIC + 1 
x4 <- sample(1:48, N, replace = TRUE) 

# Combining the variables into a matrix
xMat <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4)

head(xMat) 

#1ST MODEL: linear proba model 
u_mod1 <- rnorm(N,0,0.425)
# model coefficients
b0_mod1 <- 0.157
b1_mod1 <- 0.59
b2_mod1 <- 0.0609
b3_mod1 <- -0.420
sd_bh0_mod1 <- 0.0389
sd_bh1_mod1 <- 0.05
sd_bh2_mod1 <- 0.0523
sd_bh3_mod1 <- 0.0546

bh0_mod1 <-rnorm(N,b0_mod1,sd_bh0_mod1)
bh1_mod1 <-rnorm(N,b1_mod1,sd_bh1_mod1)
bh2_mod1 <-rnorm(N,b2_mod1,sd_bh2_mod1)
bh3_mod1 <-rnorm(N,b3_mod1,sd_bh3_mod1)

xMat_model1 <- xMat[, -c(4)]
xMat_model1_matrix <- as.matrix(xMat_model1)

# Combine coefficients into a matrix
beta_hat_model1 <- cbind(bh1_mod1, bh2_mod1, bh3_mod1)

# Transpose it
beta_hat_model1 <- t(beta_hat_model1)

# yMat = a binary variable
yMatLin_mod1 <- as.numeric(bh0_mod1 + xMat_model1_matrix  %*% 
    beta_hat_model1 + u_mod1)
library(mvtnorm)

data1 <- data.frame(xMat, yMatLin_mod1)

mod1 <- lm(yMatLin_mod1 ~ x1+x2+x3, data = data1)
summary(mod1)

# MODEL 1  : 

set.seed(8)
u_mod2 <- rnorm(N,0,1.18)
# model coefficients
b0_mod2 <- -0.0975
b1_mod2 <- 0.592
b2_mod2 <- 0.0457
b3_mod2 <- -0.418
b4_mod2 <- -0.441
sd_bh0_mod2 <- 0.0708
sd_bh1_mod2 <- 0.0539
sd_bh2_mod2 <- 0.0512
sd_bh3_mod2 <- 0.0548
sd_bh4_mod2 <- 0.0114

bh0_mod2 <-rnorm(N,b0_mod2,sd_bh0_mod2)
bh1_mod2 <-rnorm(N,b1_mod2,sd_bh1_mod2)
bh2_mod2 <-rnorm(N,b2_mod2,sd_bh2_mod2)
bh3_mod2 <-rnorm(N,b3_mod2,sd_bh3_mod2)
bh4_mod2 <-rnorm(N,b4_mod2,sd_bh4_mod2)

xMat_model2 <- xMat
xMat_model2_matrix <- as.matrix(xMat_model2)

# Combine coefficients into a matrix
beta_hat_model2 <- cbind(bh1_mod2, bh2_mod2, bh3_mod2, bh4_mod2)

# Transpose it
beta_hat_model2 <- t(beta_hat_model2)

# yMat = a binary variable
yMatLin_mod2 <- as.numeric(bh0_mod2 + xMat_model2_matrix  %*% 
    beta_hat_model2 + u_mod2)
library(mvtnorm)

data2 <- data.frame(xMat, yMatLin_mod2)

mod2 <- lm(yMatLin_mod2 ~ x1+x2+x3+x4, data = data2)
summary(mod2)

Just note that I don't know the variance of the error term and that I now that x1 and x4 are strongly correlated with it :(

Not exactly what you're looking for, but here's an interesting example of another approach to create datasets that have targeted regression properties: https://www.research.autodesk.com/publications/same-stats-different-graphs/

Also make sure to checked the information on this website about self-study questions and add this tag to your post (I believe it applies since you state that it is homework).

You can reproduce these results exactly without simulation.  The technique at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/313138/919 is a very useful tool for that, because it enables you to construct a sequence of explanatory variables with specified regression coefficients.  The tricky part is to reproduce the standard errors of estimate, because they provide information only about the diagonal of their variance-covariance matrix.  One approach is to assume all off-diagonal entries are zero.

Here are some points of thought
For the extended model

You want that the additional variable is changing the results in a particular way. For this, the additional variable needs to be correlated with the others. Potentially you need to have those other variables also correlated with each other. Why do my (coefficients, standard errors & CIs, p-values & significance) change when I add a term to my regression model?

For improving the results

In your generation of the variance of the regressor matrix like rnorm(N,b0_mod2,sd_bh0_mod2) you use simulations, but you can also standardize the noise, to make the sample with the exact variance. In the case that you need correlations than you can use mvrnorm from the MASS package, which allows you to make the mean and variance of the sample to be exactly as specified.

In addition, your added noise u_mod2 will create discrepancies if it correlates with one or more of your regressors. This you also want to model exactly such that it represents the residuals instead of the noise. (residuals and noise differ, the residuals have zero correlation with the regressor matrix)


Typo

In addition you made a typo when you specified
b4_mod2 <- -0.441
sd_bh4_mod2 <- 0.0114

The coefficient is 0.0441


Possible mistake in your approach:

Are you sure you need to model the data like two seperate data sets? Is it not that you are supposed to generate one single data set that is able to create both extended and non-extended regression models?

I wonder whether setting the standard deviation of the $X$ variable equal to the standard error of the coefficients will directly work. There should be some additional factor $n$ involved. $Cov(\beta) = (X^TX)^{-1} \hat{\sigma}^2$ and the diagonal $(X^TX)^{-1}$ is not the same as the variance of $X$
See also: Why does the variance of the OLS estimator scale with $\frac{1}{n}$?


