Generating a distribution from two correlated standard normal variables
I know it is a fairly basic question but I would like to understand the origin of the expression:
Z= $\rho$X+$\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$Y
Where X and Y are two standard normal distributions with correlation $\rho$ and Z is the joint distribution.
In all the references I've seen, this expression is taken for granted as a definition, but I have never come across with the deduction or where this comes from.

Your question doesn't seem to make much sense. What do you understand bis meant by "$X$ and $Y$ are two standard normal distributions"???  Please be very specific:  fill in the blanks in the statements $X = ____$ and $Y = ____$ with explicit mathematical formulas, not words,.

Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303/919 for a full account.  For a short, simple demonstration that doesn't require the joint normality assumption, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/313138/919.

It might be easier to restate the claim

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with standard normal distributions $\mathcal N(0,1)$ then, for any $\rho \in [-1,1]$,  $Z= \rho X+\sqrt{1-\rho^2} Y $ is a random variable with a standard normal distribution and the correlation (and covariance) between $X$ and $Z$ is $\rho$.

You can show:

since $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal, $Z$ also has a normal distribution; if you want more, you could apply a suitable convolution of the densities e.g. by completing the square in the exponent
by linearity of expectation, $\mathbb E[Z]= \rho \mathbb E[X]+\sqrt{1-\rho^2} \mathbb E[Y] = 0$
since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\textrm{Var}(Z)= \rho^2 \textrm{Var}(X)+(\sqrt{1-\rho^2})^2 \textrm{Var}(Y) = 1$
since the expectations of $X$ and $Z$ are $0$ and their variances are $1$, $\textrm{Cor}(X,Z)=\frac{\textrm{Cov}(X,Z)}{\textrm{Var}(X)\textrm{Var}(Z)}=\mathbb E[XZ] = \rho \mathbb E[X^2]+\sqrt{1-\rho^2} \mathbb E[XY] =\rho$

