How to generate N-dimensional multivariate-normal sample from N-2 marginals
I am facing a problem with my "calculator" which uses samples generated through a N-dimensional multivariate normal. I've included below a code snippet to illustrate the issue.
From sample_1 my calculator extracts:

M: a number which is sensitive to every single number in sample_1
M_n: a vector of N numbers, each sensitive to one and only one column in sample_1

Now, I need to analyze the sensitivity of my calculator to one specific element in the correlation matrix. This I do by changing the (0, 1) element in correlation_matrix_1 from 0.0 to 0.02. In short, the problem is that the 3rd column in sample_2 is different from that in sample_1. This has the undesirable result of changing M_2. Screenshots of both samples are at the end  of this message,
Now to the question: how can I generate columns 0 and 1 of sample_2 from:

column 2 of sample_1 -> Fix M_2
correlation_matrix_2

Note that I must be able to do this in general for a much larger matrix, although still by changing a single matrix element at the time.
import numpy as np


def main(correlation_matrix: np.ndarray, mc_seed: int = 1234,
         n_trials: int = 10):
    generator = np.random.default_rng(seed=mc_seed)
    segment_factor_sample = generator.multivariate_normal(
        mean=[0] * correlation_matrix.shape[0],
        cov=correlation_matrix,
        size=n_trials,
        check_valid='raise')
    return segment_factor_sample


if __name__ == '__main__':
    correlation_matrix_1 = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                                     [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                                     [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
    sample_1 = main(correlation_matrix_1)

    correlation_matrix_2 = np.array([[1.0,  0.02, 0.0],
                                     [0.02, 1.0,  0.0],
                                     [0.0,  0.0,  1.0]])
    sample_2 = main(correlation_matrix_2)


    sample_1


    
    sample_2


You want to see the effect of correlation without having the regenerate the random numbers?

The more general question of generating data having specified correlations with other data is asked and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15011, so maybe that will solve your problem?

You want to see the effect of correlation without having the regenerate the random numbers?
Try defining the variables by a linear combination of another set of variables.
E.g. $X_1, X_2, X_3$ iid normal, then
$$\begin{array}{}
Y_1 = a X_1 + (1-a) X_2 \\
Y_2 = (1-a) X_1 + a X_2 \\
Y_3 = X_3 \end{array}$$
by changing $a$ you can change the correlation of $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ but you don't have to regenerate the random part of the data.

To be honest I don't fully understand your problem but still try an answer.
For gaussian you can generate any N-dimensionnal gaussian by generating each dimension (with N independant Gaussian) then mixing then with the right matrix.
Indeed $X = (X_1, ..., X_N)$ ( with $X_i$ the independant Gaussian) gives a N-dimensionnal Gaussian with Identity Covariance.
Then you just need to take the squareroot (in matrix sense, so with Cholesky decomposition since correlation matrix have good properties) and multiply X by it to get the gaussian you target.
Since Multiplication is deterministic, if you don't change the $X_i$ you do not change the $Y_i$.
Does it answer the question?
