# How to generate two negatively correlated random series of numbers?

Tags: r, correlation, random-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate correlated random numbers (given means, variances and degree of correlation)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/how-to-generate-correlated-random-numbers-given-means-variances-and-degree-of)

I have been trying to generate two random variables with correlation of -0.9 but have not been successful. I have tried:

```
x1 <- rnorm(200, mean=0, sd=1)
x2 <- rnorm(200, mean=0, sd=1) 
z <- -0.9*x1+sqrt((1-(-0.9)))*x2
cor(x1,z)
```

But it did not work.

I tried also the [?mvrnorm](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/mvrnorm.html) function, but it did not work either. How I can get this done??

Comment: I don't know why `mvrnorm` didn't work, note that @user603 [demonstrates](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48534/how-to-generate-two-negatively-correlated-random-series-of-numbers/48535#48535) its use properly. Note also that my answer at the linked thread provides a way of generating correlated numbers exactly along the lines you're going for here (although I agree that you don't need to re-invent the wheel).

Comment: Your expression in your line of code for `z` is wrong. (Note that even when you get it right, the sample correlation will still vary somewhat from -0.9)

Answer (score 5):

Don't re-invent the wheel!

```
library(MASS)
M<-matrix(-0.9,2,2)
diag(M)<-1
X<-mvrnorm(200,rep(0,2),M,empirical=TRUE)
cor(X)
```