# Omitted Variable Bias in Linear Regression - Simulation

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, simulation, bias

***Is the following a reasonable illustration of the OVB problem?***

We build up fictional data around the regression line:

$$y = 7.2 + 2.3 \, x_1 + 0.1 \, x_2 + 1.5 \, x_3 + 0.013 \, x_4 + \varepsilon$$

by using this function:

```
correlatedValue = function(x, r){
  r2 = r**2
  ve = 1 - r2
  SD = sqrt(ve)
  e  = rnorm(length(x), mean = 0, sd = SD)
  y  = r * x + e
}
```

-thank you, @gung for this post:
[How to generate correlated random numbers (given means, variances and degree of correlation)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/how-to-generate-correlated-random-numbers-given-means-variances-and-degree-of)

And the following function, which generates four variables (***x1***, ***x2***, ***x3*** and ***x4***) as well as noise (***eps***). ***x1*** and ***x3*** are sample from normal distributions; ***x2*** is extracted from a uniform; and ***x4*** from a Poisson.

```
variables <- function(){
x <- rnorm(1000)
x1 <- 50 + 15 * x
x3 <- 28 + 11 * correlatedValue(x = x, r = 0.6)
x2 <- runif(1000, 0, 100)
x4 <- rpois(1000,50)
eps <- rnorm(1000,5, 7)
y = 7.2 + 2.3 * x1 + 0.001 * x2 + 1.5 * x3 + 0.013 * x4 + eps
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(y, x1, x2, x3, x4))
c <- as.numeric(coef(lm(y ~ x2 + x3 + x4, dat))[3])
d <- as.numeric(coef(lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, dat))[4])
c(c,d)
}
```

***x1*** and ***x3*** are highly influential on ***y*** and are correlated with each other, setting the values up to observe ***OVB***. ***x2*** and ***x4*** are less influential.

Here is the plotting of ***y*** against ***x1***, ***x2***, ***x3***  and ***x4***, and ***x1*** over ***x3*** with added regression lines:

[image]

And following is the variance-covariance matrix:

```
             y           x1           x2         x3          x4
y   1.00000000  0.944410945  0.014421682 0.77571067 -0.01463981
x1  0.94441094  1.000000000 -0.001726526 0.56504020 -0.03562991
x2  0.01442168 -0.001726526  1.000000000 0.03537959  0.02253922
x3  0.77571067  0.565040198  0.035379590 1.00000000  0.02573827
x4 -0.01463981 -0.035629906  0.022539218 0.02573827  1.00000000
```

Predictably, the regression including all variables shows similar coefficients to the initial equation:

```
coef(lm(y~.,dat))[2:5]
         x1          x2          x3          x4 
2.253353226 0.004899445 1.547915198 0.017710038
```

Wrapping up, a quick simulation is carried out to obtain the mean of the ***x3*** coefficient in 1,000 simulations *WITHOUT* including ***x1*** ("coef_x3") and then *WITH* ***x1*** ("coef_x3_full"):

```
coef_x3 <- NULL
coef_x3_full <- NULL
for (i in 1:1000){
  coef_x3[i] = variables()[1]
  coef_x3_full[i] = variables()[2]
}
mean(coef_x3)
mean(coef_x3_full)
```

obtaining a coefficient for ***x3*** of **3.383** when ***x1*** is excluded versus a coefficient for ***x3*** of **1.502** when included. So when ***x1*** is included we have an unbiased estimation of the true ***x3*** coefficient (***1.5***), whereas the estimation is biased when we exclude ***x1***.