# R's lm prediction interval vs simulation

Tags: r, simulation, prediction-interval, lm

I was trying to simulate the prediction interval for lm model in R, but I found out that my prediction interval is consistently biased. I've attached the code, and a sample figure below. Any idea why?

```
n = 20     # number of points
N = 10000  # simulation rounds
x = 1:n    # x
s = 200    # standard deviation of error

set.seed(12)
e = rnorm(n, 0, s)

a = 5; b = 5  # slope, intercept

y = a * x + b + e

## lm model
mod1 = lm(y ~ x)
summ_mod1 = summary(mod1)

## std errors
coefs = summ_mod1$coefficients[, 1:2]
sigma = summ_mod1$sigma

## predict new data using simulation
new.x = (min(x) - 2 * max(x)):(max(x) + 2 * max(x))

upper = rep(0, length(new.x))
lower = rep(0, length(new.x))
tmp   = rep(0, N)

for (i in 1:length(new.x)) {
  tmp = rnorm(n = N, mean = coefs[1, 1], sd = coefs[1, 2]) +
        rnorm(n = N, mean = coefs[2, 1], sd = coefs[2, 2]) * new.x[i] +
        rnorm(n = N, mean = 0, sd = sigma)

  upper[i] = mean(tmp) + 1.96 * sd(tmp)
  lower[i] = mean(tmp) - 1.96 * sd(tmp)
}

plot(x, y, type = "p", 
     xlim = c(min(new.x), max(new.x)),
     ylim = c(min(lower), max(upper)))
lines(new.x, lower, col = "blue")
lines(new.x, upper, col = "blue")

## R's prediction interval
pred.int =  predict(object = mod1, 
                    newdata = data.frame(x = new.x), 
                    interval = "predict")

pred.lower = pred.int[,2]
pred.upper = pred.int[,3]

lines(new.x, pred.lower, col = "red")
lines(new.x, pred.upper, col = "red")

legend(x = -40, y = 1500, 
       legend = c("simulation", "predict.lm"),
       lty = c(1, 1),
       col = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image: Prediction interval]

Comment: Could you also describe your simulation extra to providing the code for it?

Comment: Your simulation is ignoring the covariance between the estimated parameters.

Comment: Yes, that's very true! How do I incorporate that into my simulation?

Comment: Richard, I'm basically sampling both the estimated parameters (slope and intercept), and the errors (residuals), to get a distribution of response for every new data point, and draw the 95% confidence interval for each point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to atireto's comment, I realized that I haven't taken into account the covariances between the estimated parameters. I was assuming that *a* and *b* are uncorrelated random variables, but they are not. So I corrected the sampling of *a* and *b* by converting them to correlated random variables using Cholesky decomposition of variance-covariance matrix ([see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/how-to-generate-correlated-random-numbers-given-means-variances-and-degree-of)).

Here's the corrected code:

```
rm(list = ls())

n = 20     # number of points
N = 10000  # simulation rounds
x = 1:n    # x
s = 200    # standard deviation of error

set.seed(12)
e = rnorm(n, 0, s)

a = 5; b = 5  # slope, intercept

y = a * x + b + e

## lm model
mod1 = lm(y ~ x)
summ_mod1 = summary(mod1)

## std errors
coefs = summ_mod1$coefficients[, 1:2]
sigma = summ_mod1$sigma

## predict new data using simulation
new.x = (min(x) - 2 * max(x)):(max(x) + 2 * max(x))

upper = rep(0, length(new.x))
lower = rep(0, length(new.x))
tmp   = rep(0, N)

for (i in 1:length(new.x)) {
  tmp = rnorm(n = N, mean = coefs[1, 1], sd = coefs[1, 2]) +
        rnorm(n = N, mean = coefs[2, 1], sd = coefs[2, 2]) * new.x[i] +
        rnorm(n = N, mean = 0, sd = sigma)

  upper[i] = mean(tmp) + 1.96 * sd(tmp)
  lower[i] = mean(tmp) - 1.96 * sd(tmp)
}

plot(x, y, type = "p", 
     xlim = c(min(new.x), max(new.x)),
     ylim = c(min(lower), max(upper)))
lines(new.x, lower, col = "blue")
lines(new.x, upper, col = "blue")

## R's prediction interval
pred.int =  predict(object = mod1, 
                    newdata = data.frame(x = new.x), 
                    interval = "predict",
                    level = 0.95)

pred.lower = pred.int[,2]
pred.upper = pred.int[,3]

lines(new.x, pred.lower, col = "red")
lines(new.x, pred.upper, col = "red")

## taking the variance-covariance matrix into account
L = chol(vcov(mod1))

for (i in 1:length(new.x)) {
  beta = matrix(c(rnorm(n = N),
                  rnorm(n = N)), 
                nrow = 2)

  beta_cor = t(L) %*% beta

  tmp = coefs[1, 1] + beta_cor[1, ] +
        (coefs[2, 1] + beta_cor[2, ]) * new.x[i] +
        rnorm(n = N, mean = 0, sd = sigma)

  upper[i] = mean(tmp) + 1.96 * sd(tmp)
  lower[i] = mean(tmp) - 1.96 * sd(tmp)
}

lines(new.x, lower, col = "green")
lines(new.x, upper, col = "green")

legend(x = -40, y = 1600, 
       legend = c("sim - without cor", "sim - with co", "predict.lm"),
       lty = c(1, 1, 1),
       col = c("blue", "green", "red"))
```

[image]

It still doesn't perfectly match the R's predict.lm result, but it's very close. In fact, if I change the 1.96 coefficient to something like 2.1, it matches it perfectly. Predict.lm is supposed to be 95% prediction interval, so I'm not sure this is happening.

Comment: As I decrease/increase the number of points, the gap between my simulation and predict.lm's result increases/decreases. I can't figure out exactly why though... What am I missing here?

Comment: The prediction interval from predict is using a t-value based on the sample size, which will approach 1.96 as it gets larger. Try replacing 1.96 in your simulation with qt(0.975,n)

Comment: Thanks! It's much better now, but it still doesn't match it completely though, especially for smaller n, e.g. n = 5.

Comment: At that sample size you need is confidence limits on your confidence limits to be able to say if they are different or not!