# How to generate correlated random variables with higher comoments

Tags: correlation, random-variable, covariance, covariance-matrix

I am aware that given the covariance matrix, we can generate correlated random variables by Cholesky Decomposition or SVD. (viz. [How to generate correlated random numbers (given means, variances and degree of correlation)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/how-to-generate-correlated-random-numbers-given-means-variances-and-degree-of))
I am interested to know if we could extend this idea to generate correlated random variables using higher comoments, such as the symmetric cokurtosis?