# Simulating iid mean zero Matérn processes

Tags: r, self-study, functional-data-analysis

I'm currently learning FDA (functional data analysis), following "Introduction to Functional Data Analysis" by Kokoszka & Reimherr. Here it is exercice 1.5:

> **1.5** The Matérn covariance function leads to a very general family of stationary Gaussian processes. The form of the covariance function is:
>
> $C(t,s)=\frac{\sigma^2}{\Gamma(\nu)2^{\nu-1}}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{2\nu}|t-s|}{\rho}\bigg)^\nu K_\nu \bigg(\frac{\sqrt{2\nu}|t-s|}{\rho}\bigg)^\nu $
>
> where $\sigma^2$ is the variance parameter, ν the smoothness parameter, and ρ the range parameter. K_ν(·) is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.
> The paths of the Matérn process are k times continuously differentiable for any ν > k, with probability one.
> **1.** Simulate and plot 100 iid mean zero Matérn processes with ν = 1/2, ν = 2,
> and ν = 4. Set σ
> 2 = 1 and ρ = 1. Use a temporal grid with 50 evenly
> spaced points. Do not use an R package to do this directly. Program it
> using the besselK() function and using it to define the covariance matrix
> on the grid of time points.

I simply don't know how to simulate the random variables just given the covariance function. Any help on how to do this would help me a lot!

Comment: It reads like it's testing your ability to generate a multivariate Gaussian distribution, given its mean and covariance matrix.  That's ordinarily done by computing a square root of the covariance, as explained (and coded in `R` and Python) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120179.  Perhaps that answers your question?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, 
please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $Z = (Z_1, \ldots, Z_p)$ has a standard multivariate Normal distribution (all means are zero and the covariance matrix is the identity), then for $p\times p$ matrices $Q$ and $\Delta,$

$$X = Q \Delta Z$$

has covariance matrix

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X) = E[X X^\prime] = Q\Delta E[Z Z^\prime] \Delta^\prime Q^\prime = Q(\Delta\Delta^\prime)Q^\prime.$$

Thus, if you wish this matrix to equal a specified covariance matrix $\Sigma,$ it suffices to *diagonalize* $\Sigma.$  The Spectral Theorem says there exists an orthogonal matrix $Q$ and *diagonal* matrix $\Lambda$ for which

$$\Sigma = Q \Lambda Q^\prime$$

and, because $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite, all the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ have square roots.  Let $\Delta$ be the diagonal matrix of the square roots of the entries of $\Lambda.$

You generate values of $Z$ by generating independent standard normal values of the $Z_i.$

**Here, then, is a quick and dirty `R` function to generate `n` *iid* realizations of $X.$**  It uses `eigen` to compute $Q$ and $\Lambda$ and `sqrt` to take the square roots.  Each realization is a column in the output matrix.

```R
rmnorm <- function(n, Sigma) {
  with(eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE), {
    p <- length(values)
    tcrossprod(vectors %*% diag(sqrt(pmax(values, 0)), p), matrix(rnorm(n * p), n))
  })
}
```

The `pmax(...)` stuff deals with situations where floating point error creates tiny negative eigenvalues.  To avoid further problems, we replace them with true zeros before attempting to take a square root.

**It will be convenient to encapsulate the Matérn covariance in a function.** Here is its correct evaluation.  The only numerical twist is that we have to specify its value at $0$ explicitly, for otherwise we might find ourselves multiplying $0$ by an infinity.

```R
C <- function(x, nu = 1, rho = 1, sigma = 1, tol = 1e-8) {
  d <- abs(x) * sqrt(2 * nu) / rho
  ifelse(d <= tol, 1, (d^nu * besselK(d, nu)) * 2^(1-nu) / gamma(nu)) * sigma^2
}
```

**The rest is a matter of looping.**  As far as responding to the exercise goes, I think it's more revealing (a) to use $\nu\in\{1/2, 1, 4\}$ because the qualitative nature of a series with $\nu=1$ will be visibly different than series with $\nu\gt 1,$ all of which rather similar; (b) to reduce the realizations from $100$ to around $30$ so you can see the individual series; and (c) to use several hundred points instead of $50$ to show the detail.

[image]

Theory explains that the "jaggedness" of each series is determined by how differentiable the covariance function is at a lag of zero, so I have plotted the covariance functions for reference.

**Below is the looping code.**  It uses one optimization: the entries in the covariance matrix are the values of $C$ at all the possible distances between the time points $x.$  There are only $150-1$ distances with $150$ *evenly spaced* points, even though the matrix contains $150^2 = 22,500$ entries.  We therefore save a great deal of computing by first calculating those $150-1$ values (in the array `s`, which does double duty by providing the heights for the plot of $C$) and then scattering them appropriately through the covariance matrix `S`.  This makes the code execute almost instantaneously.

```R
x <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 150)           # The evenly-spaced time points
mu <- seq(1, 4, length.out = 30)           # Mean height of each series in its plot
cols <- hsv(runif(length(mu), 0.02, 0.65)) # A range of random colors, one per series
set.seed(17)                               # To reproduce the figure exactly
par(mfcol= c(2,3))                         # Place the plots in a 2 X 3 grid
for (nu in c(1/2, 1, 4)) {                 # The smoothness parameters to use
  s <- C(x - x[1], nu = nu)
  plot(x - x[1], s, type = "l", ylim = 0:1, lwd = 2, xlab = "Lag", ylab = "",
        main = bquote(paste("Matérn Covariance for ", nu==.(nu))))

  S <- outer(seq_along(x), seq_along(x), \(i,j) s[abs(i - j) + 1])
  y <- scale(rmnorm(length(mu), S), scale = FALSE) + rep(mu, each = length(x))

  plot(range(x), range(mu) + c(-1, 1), type = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "Value",
       main = bquote(paste("Time series for ", nu==.(nu))))
  sapply(seq_along(mu), \(j) lines(x, y[, j], col = cols[j]))
}
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```