# How to simulate two datasets that satisfy specific constraints such as having specific mean , standard deviation, and correlation coefficient?

Tags: correlation, python, sample, random-generation

I know that generating different random datasets having certain standard deviation and mean values are possible.
However, I'm just wondering if it's also possible to generate, let's say 2 datasets, with certain standard deviation, mean values, and a specified correlation coefficient in between them.

Thanks in advance
Best

Comment: Also relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/how-to-generate-correlated-random-numbers-given-means-variances-and-degree-of

Comment: Normally distributed? Something else?

Comment: @Henry Yes, exactly normally distributed. I forgot to add it.

Comment: @COOLSerdash It doesn't answer because that question doesn't include a "pre-specified" correlation coefficient in between two normally generated datasets.

Comment: There are multiple threads that answer your question of how to simulate correlated random variables. In addition to the ones I already linked to, here are some more: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32169/how-can-i-generate-data-with-a-prespecified-correlation-matrix, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13382/how-to-define-a-distribution-such-that-draws-from-it-correlate-with-a-draw-from